# use LINQ to query a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list like the below from a text file which I read in using *StreamReader.ReadLine* into a string list:

```
CSAclsEN    001 \\sgprt\Projects2   001 CSAclsEN-2010-1130227   10:42   27Feb13 2010    Southgate Branch    SS01    001 ****69  Steve Suttill   
01  ******10    Business Current Account    GBP 2,342,188.38    
02  27Feb13 Cheque Cashed   700.00- 
02  27Feb13 Cheque Cashed   25.00-  
02  27Feb13 Cheque Cashed   1,000.00-   
02  27Feb13 Cheque Cashed   1,000.00-   
02  27Feb13 CHS 4123-690069-100 20.00-  
01  ******11    Personal Current Account    GBP 22,456.80   
02  27Feb13 Cash Withdrawn  100.00- 
02  27Feb13 TFR 130227SS0100103 1,000.00    
02  27Feb13 TFR 130227SS0100091 1,234.56    
02  27Feb13 TFR 130227SS0100066 2,222.22    
02  27Feb13 TFR 130227SS0100064 0.01
```

what I want to do is:

1. Output the first line once as the mini statement header
2. each time the first two characters in a line are **01** I will output header information for that account
3. followed by a formatted list of the lines with **02** until the next line with **01** where I will output the header information again and so on.

(this is for customer mini statements in a Cashier application)

I am writing this to an MS Word template using Office.Interop

Is LINQ the best way to go in order to seperate the different types of records, and how would I do that?

The output (in an MS Word template) would be like this - **but without the borders** :

[image]

The template has only the top two (**and the second table starts with only one row under Date**, and there will be a variable number of accounts (beginning with **02**) so each time an **02** is encounter by the code, the second table you see in the picture would be copied, or maybe a new table added with the same columns and a row added for each line wityh **01**

The template looks like this at the start:
[image]

And as each line with **01** is encountered a new row is added below, then when a line with **02** is encountered, a new table is started.

**More information:**
This is an enhancement to an existing application that already handles a similar list but having only one account with transactions.

Currently I replace the "{}" fields with data by mapping *key-value pairs* in a Dictionary then start handling the transactions like this:

```
int iRow=1;

for (int s = 1; s < pqRequests.Count; s++)
    {                                                                              
    string[] sValues = pqRequests[s].Split('\t');

    // Transaction List
    for (int iDx = 2; iDx <= 5; iDx++)
        {
        oWordDoc.Tables[2].Cell(iRow, iDx).Range.Text = sValues[iDx - 1];
        }
    }

    oWordDoc.Tables[2].Rows.Add(ref oMissing);                                            
    iRow++;
    }
```

Now, I'd like to keep my handling of the Account list mini statement within the same procedure, but am not sure about the best way to go forward

Comment: *list of thelines with 01 until the next line with 01* Did you mean * list of thelines with **02** until the next line with 01*

Comment: LINQ can help you to do that, but can you provide the exact output you need?

Comment: @DominicKexel: yes you are right, I made a mistake

Comment: List the desired output (make a mock-up). The question is still not clear.

Comment: If you are reading it to a single string you could split at 01 and have all of your data separated for each account. Then allocate the data accordingly.

Comment: @TraeMoore: yes that is what I am doing with the simpler list, that only has one account + several transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think LINQ will be the most readeable option here.
Just use classic loop will improve maintainbility:

```
var groupResults = new List<Tuple<string, List<string>>>();
List<string> subLines = null;
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    if(line.StartsWith("01"))
    {
        subLines = new List<string>();
        groupResults.Add(Tuple.Create(line, subLines));
    }
    // consider to handle the case where a line begin with 02 with no 01 before
    else if(subLines != null && line.StartsWith("02"))
    {
        subLines.Add(line);
    }
}
```

You have your results, grouped by headers, with the list of 02 corresponding.
You can easily do the formatting based on this list of list now.

Comment: The way I read the reqs there seems no reason for any grouping. Just a reformatting, line by line.